# How to use LIKE ANY in JPQL with array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I am working with jpql native queries.

I have a working postgresql query that i need to implement in jpql.

Select * from sql_sent_sms where match_url LIKE any (array['%ctid=123%','%ctid=231%']);

This displays all rows with the that matches value of column match_url to the array.

Now i want to use this in jpa native query but it gives me error while providing the array.

This is what i have tried:

```
    List<String> arrctid =  Arrays.asList("%ctid=2141234%","%ctid=4be2a864-6e20-4686-b0f2-e3f432752c3d%");

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT test.receiver  FROM Sql_test test"+"WHERE test.match_url like any (arrctid) and test.service=:sysuserId ");
query.setParameter("arrctid", arrctid );
query.setParameter("sysuserId", sysuserId);
```

I have also tried

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT test.receiver  FROM Sql_test test"+"WHERE test.match_url like any (:arrctid) and test.service=:sysuserId ");

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT test.receiver  FROM Sql_test test"+"WHERE test.match_url like any :arrctid and test.service=:sysuserId ");
```

But nothing is working.

Can anybody tell me how to set array parameter with like any operator.

Comment: `LIKE ANY (ARRAY[:arrctid])` in a **native query** *may* work, but I never tried. JPA binds each list element, not the entire list/array (I don't think that's possible with JPA, but only with direct JDBC calls at the moment).